Can you make 5 x 3 “magic” rectangles?
Warmup question:
Using all the numbers 1, 2, 3, ... 15, each exactly once, can you construct a matrix with 5 rows and 3 columns such that all the row sums are equal?
Main question:
Using all the numbers 1, 2, 3, ... 15, each exactly once, can you construct a matrix with 5 rows and 3 columns such that all the row sums are equal AND all the column sums are equal?

Partial answers are welcome!

Here is a grid that does both:

 

I used trial and error, but there was a key insight that made it fairly trivial:

 The eight odd numbers must be in 4 pairs of 2 along the rows, or the sum of the row with the odd number will be odd- and the magic number along the rows must be 24. Similarly, it was important to ensure an even number of odd numbers along each column; my solution had 2, 4, 2, but 4, 4, 0 may be possible as well.


The other kind of solution, hinted at by @ilikecorgis:

 $\begin{array}{ccccc}1&3&7&15&14\\13&9&11&5&2\\10&12&6&4&8\end{array}$


If anyone knows how to draw a line separating the odds and evens, feel free to suggest an edit!

You can find all the possible combinations using the Python script:
itertools import permutations
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Generator


def permutations_with_remaining(
    items: tuple[int, ...],
    indexes: tuple[int, ...],
    n: int,
    total: int,
) -> Generator[tuple[tuple[int, ...], tuple[int, ...], tuple[int, ...]], None, None]:
    """Pick any n of the items that sum to the given total.

    Args:
        items: The items to pick from.
        indexes: The indexes to pick from.
        n: The number of items to pick.
        total: The expected total for the picked items.

    Yields:
        Three tuples representing the picked values, picked indexes (in the order
        corresponding to the picked values), and unpicked indexes (in their original
        order).
    """
    for picked_indexes in permutations(indexes, n):
        picked = tuple(items[i] for i in picked_indexes)
        if sum(picked) != total:
            continue
        unpicked_indexes = tuple(i for i in indexes if i not in picked_indexes)
        yield picked, picked_indexes, unpicked_indexes


def valid_ordered_first_row(
    indexes: tuple[int, ...],
) -> bool:
    """Whether the items in the first row are valid and ordered.

    Args:
        indexes: The indexes to of the items in the first row.

    Returns:
        True if the the first row contains the initial index and if all the
        indexes are ordered.
    """
    return  (
        indexes[0] == 0
        and all(indexes[i] < indexes[i + 1] for i in range(len(indexes) - 1))
    )


def magic_rectangles(
    items: tuple[int, ...],
    row_size: int,
    ordered: bool = True,
) -> Generator[tuple[tuple[int, ...], ...], None, None]:
    """Find magic rectangles for the given items.

    A megic rectangle arranges the items into a rectangular matrix, with the given row
    size, where all the rows sum to the same value and all the columns sum to the same
    value.

    Args:
        items: The items to arrange into magic rectangles.
        row_size: The number of items in each row.
        ordered: Whether to only output ordered magic rectangles (with the first item
            in the top-left matrix cell and the top-row and left-column ordered) or to
            output all permutations of magic rectangles.

    Yields:
        Each valid magic rectangle.
    """
    column_size, column_rem = divmod(len(items), row_size)
    assert column_rem == 0
    row_total, row_rem = divmod(sum(items), column_size)
    col_total, col_rem = divmod(sum(items), row_size)
    assert row_rem == 0
    assert col_rem == 0

    row_indexes = []
    row_values = []
    row_stack = [
        permutations_with_remaining(
            items,
            tuple(range(len(items))),
            row_size,
            row_total
        ),
    ]
    while row_stack:
        try:
            row, picked_indexes, remaining_indexes = next(row_stack[-1])
            if ordered and (
                picked_indexes[0] < row_indexes[-1]
                if row_values
                else not valid_ordered_first_row(picked_indexes)
            ):
                continue
            if remaining_indexes:
                row_indexes.append(picked_indexes[0])
                row_values.append(row)
                row_stack.append(
                    permutations_with_remaining(
                        items,
                        remaining_indexes,
                        row_size,
                        row_total,
                    ),
                )
            else:
                rows = (*row_values, row)
                for column in zip(*rows):
                    if sum(column) != col_total:
                        break
                else:
                    yield rows
        except StopIteration:
            _ = row_stack.pop()
            if row_values:
                _ = row_values.pop()
                _ = row_indexes.pop()


solution = list(magic_rectangles(tuple(range(1, 5*3 + 1)), 3))
pprint(solution)


Generate successive rows ensuring that each sums to the correct total.
Once all the rows have been generated, check that the columns add to the correct total.
It is possible to eliminate further permutations of rectangles as rectangles can be considered duplicates if you can re-order the rows and columns so that the initial value is in the top-left and that the values of the top-row and left-column are sorted.

Which gives the output:
[((1, 8, 15), (2, 9, 13), (11, 10, 3), (12, 7, 5), (14, 6, 4)),
 ((1, 8, 15), (2, 13, 9), (11, 10, 3), (12, 5, 7), (14, 4, 6)),
 ((1, 8, 15), (3, 7, 14), (11, 9, 4), (12, 10, 2), (13, 6, 5)),
 ((1, 8, 15), (4, 14, 6), (10, 11, 3), (12, 5, 7), (13, 2, 9)),
 ((1, 8, 15), (5, 12, 7), (9, 13, 2), (11, 3, 10), (14, 4, 6)),
 ((1, 8, 15), (6, 13, 5), (9, 4, 11), (10, 12, 2), (14, 3, 7)),
 ((1, 8, 15), (7, 3, 14), (9, 11, 4), (10, 12, 2), (13, 6, 5)),
 ((1, 8, 15), (7, 14, 3), (9, 11, 4), (10, 2, 12), (13, 5, 6)),
 ((1, 9, 14), (3, 6, 15), (11, 8, 5), (12, 10, 2), (13, 7, 4)),
 ((1, 9, 14), (3, 8, 13), (10, 12, 2), (11, 6, 7), (15, 5, 4)),
 ((1, 9, 14), (3, 8, 13), (10, 12, 2), (11, 7, 6), (15, 4, 5)),
 ((1, 9, 14), (3, 11, 10), (8, 12, 4), (13, 6, 5), (15, 2, 7)),
 ((1, 9, 14), (4, 7, 13), (8, 11, 5), (12, 10, 2), (15, 3, 6)),
 ((1, 9, 14), (4, 13, 7), (8, 5, 11), (12, 10, 2), (15, 3, 6)),
 ((1, 9, 14), (5, 4, 15), (10, 12, 2), (11, 7, 6), (13, 8, 3)),
 ((1, 9, 14), (5, 11, 8), (7, 4, 13), (12, 10, 2), (15, 6, 3)),
 ((1, 9, 14), (5, 15, 4), (10, 2, 12), (11, 6, 7), (13, 8, 3)),
 ((1, 9, 14), (6, 3, 15), (8, 11, 5), (12, 10, 2), (13, 7, 4)),
 ((1, 9, 14), (6, 11, 7), (8, 3, 13), (10, 12, 2), (15, 5, 4)),
 ((1, 9, 14), (6, 11, 7), (8, 13, 3), (10, 2, 12), (15, 5, 4)),
 ((1, 10, 13), (2, 7, 15), (11, 8, 5), (12, 9, 3), (14, 6, 4)),
 ((1, 10, 13), (2, 15, 7), (11, 8, 5), (12, 3, 9), (14, 4, 6)),
 ((1, 10, 13), (3, 12, 9), (7, 6, 11), (14, 8, 2), (15, 4, 5)),
 ((1, 10, 13), (3, 12, 9), (7, 11, 6), (14, 2, 8), (15, 5, 4)),
 ((1, 10, 13), (4, 6, 14), (9, 12, 3), (11, 5, 8), (15, 7, 2)),
 ((1, 10, 13), (4, 14, 6), (8, 5, 11), (12, 9, 3), (15, 2, 7)),
 ((1, 10, 13), (4, 14, 6), (8, 11, 5), (12, 3, 9), (15, 2, 7)),
 ((1, 10, 13), (5, 4, 15), (9, 12, 3), (11, 6, 7), (14, 8, 2)),
 ((1, 10, 13), (7, 11, 6), (8, 2, 14), (9, 12, 3), (15, 5, 4)),
 ((1, 11, 12), (2, 14, 8), (9, 5, 10), (13, 4, 7), (15, 6, 3)),
 ((1, 11, 12), (2, 14, 8), (9, 5, 10), (13, 7, 4), (15, 3, 6)),
 ((1, 11, 12), (2, 15, 7), (10, 5, 9), (13, 3, 8), (14, 6, 4)),
 ((1, 11, 12), (3, 15, 6), (9, 5, 10), (13, 7, 4), (14, 2, 8)),
 ((1, 11, 12), (5, 10, 9), (6, 4, 14), (13, 8, 3), (15, 7, 2)),
 ((1, 11, 12), (5, 10, 9), (6, 14, 4), (13, 3, 8), (15, 2, 7)),
 ((1, 11, 12), (6, 4, 14), (8, 13, 3), (10, 5, 9), (15, 7, 2)),
 ((1, 11, 12), (6, 14, 4), (8, 3, 13), (10, 5, 9), (15, 7, 2)),
 ((1, 11, 12), (7, 4, 13), (8, 14, 2), (9, 5, 10), (15, 6, 3)),
 ((1, 11, 12), (7, 15, 2), (8, 3, 13), (10, 5, 9), (14, 6, 4))]

Finding all 39 unique solutions (eliminating duplicates that could be found by re-ordering the rows and columns).
If you want all possible permutations of magic rectangle then:
solution = list(magic_rectangles(tuple(range(1, 5*3 + 1)), 3, ordered=False))

Which will generate 28,080 magic rectangles ($28080 = 39 \times 3! \times 5!$, since there are $3!$ ways to re-order the 3 columns and $5!$ ways to re-order the 5 rows).

Another possibility.

 $\begin{pmatrix}14&6&4\\7&15&2\\3&8&13\\5&10&9\\11&1&12\end{pmatrix}$


 Where the sum of all rows is 24 and the sum of all columns is 40


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Here's another:



C1
C2
C3




12
10
2


7
11
6


8
13
3


9
1
14


4
5
15




Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Thank you for fixing that markup, bobble!
